# Kafka - zookeeper doesn't run with others

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

I have a problem with Apache kafka

I have 4 clusters where I want to install kafka instances. On 3 clusters its works, they can product, and consume messages between each other, zookepers work fine. But on 4th cluster I can't run zookeeper connected with others zookeepers. If I set in zoo.cfg only local server (0.0.0.0:2888:3888) zookeeper runs in mode standalone, but if I add others servers I get error

```
 ./zkServer.sh status

ZooKeeper JMX enabled by default
Using config: /etc/zookeeper/conf/zoo.cfg
Error contacting service. It is probably not running.
```

How I can fix this error? I will add, that I can ping servers, so they can see each other.

Comment: Is the port 2181 open?

Comment: disable the `selinux` and try again.

Comment: thx for reply, on this moment all 4 nodes works, i dont know why, but when i started zookeeper this overwrite my settings in zoo.cfg

Comment: Is your problem solved now?

Comment: i think that yes, zookeepers don't show error when i run them

Comment: Congratulations